# How to send sms to another phone in c#?

Tags: c#, sms

I want to send SMS from my mobile phone to another mobile phone on C# application. I have a few questions here.

1. How to connect simcard and allow it to send SMS from my pc? (I want the receiver to know my phone number. Can I use simcard reader to do this?)
2. Is there any library, or example?

Comment: +1 for the question, -1 for the way u asked it

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly do you want. So, you have a phone connected to your PC and you want to send an SMS through your phone from a C# application on your PC? How is the phone connected? What kind of phone is it?

Comment: @nawfal I try to search on the internet but I don't know where to start. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: @svick I want to connect my phone, or just a hardware that can send SMS from my PC. I don't try to connect my phone yet because I don't know where to start. Sorry if this sound totally a dump question but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to use SMS gateway

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway

An example article from the past:
http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/zeep_mobile_free_sms_gateway.php

One more link:
http://textoo.in/help/iphone/which-gateway-should-i-choose/